# How to increase the speed of Perl DBI

Tags: perl

I am using to Perl DBI to select and process data from an MS Access database.The code works well but it is very slow.It takes 3-4 minutes to select data from my database which has only around 150 records.
I am preparing the statements outside the loop only.Tried using the fetchrow_array,fetchrow_arrayref,fetchall_arrayref methods,but the performance does not differ much.How can i improve the speed of execution?

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:ODBC:driver=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb);dbq=D:\Project\Project\BSC_KPIMonitoring\CHN\E_BSC_KPIMonitorDB.mdb');
my $stat1="SELECT * FROM SDCCHBLOCKING WHERE NE=?";
my $sth1 = $dbh->prepare($stat1);
my $stat2="SELECT * FROM SDCCHDROP WHERE NE=?";
my $sth2 = $dbh->prepare($stat2);
my $stat3="SELECT * FROM TCHBLOCKING WHERE NE=?";
my $sth3 = $dbh->prepare($stat3);
my $stat4="SELECT * FROM TCHDROP WHERE NE=?";
my $sth4 = $dbh->prepare($stat4);

my $sqlstatement="SELECT * FROM KPI_Master";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sqlstatement);
$sth->execute ||
  die "Could not execute SQL statement ... maybe invalid?";
while (my @row=$sth->fetchrow_array()){
$bsc = $row[0];
$kpi = $row[1]; 
$thresh= $row[2];

if($kpi eq "SDCCHBLOCKING")
{
$sth1->execute($bsc) ||
 die "Could not execute SQL statement ... maybe invalid?";
while (my @row1=$sth1->fetchrow_array())
  {
           if($row1[2]>$thresh)
          {
              print "SB,$bsc,$thresh,/$row1[2]";
          }
  }
 }

 if($kpi eq "SDCCHDROP")
  {
  $sth2->execute($bsc) ||
 die "Could not execute SQL statement ... maybe invalid?";
while (my @row2=$sth2->fetchrow_array())
 {
    if($row2[2]>$thresh)
          {
              print "SD,$bsc,$thresh,/$row2[2]";
          }
  }
}

if($kpi eq "TCHBLOCKING")
  {
   $sth3->execute($bsc) ||
     die "Could not execute SQL statement ... maybe invalid?";
 while (my @row3=$sth3->fetchrow_array())
 {
    if($row3[2]>$thresh)
          {
              print "TB,$bsc,$thresh,/$row3[2]";
          }
   }
 }
if($kpi eq "TCHDROP")
 {
   $sth4->execute($bsc) ||
     die "Could not execute SQL statement ... maybe invalid?";
  while (my @row4=$sth4->fetchrow_array())
   {
        if($row4[2]>$thresh)
          {
              print "TD,$bsc,$thresh,/$row4[2]";
          }
    }
  }
```

Any ideas to improve the performance?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are manually testing if `$row[2]` is greater than `$thresh`. Move that condition into the SQL queries, if possible: `... AND third_col > ?`!

Comment: thats a good idea..but i dont think it will have an effect on speed;the resultset of the queries will have only 4 or 5 rows.

Comment: You are right, that was irrelevant on this scale. Have you benchmarked it to determine where the bottleneck could be? I recommend the excellent [`Devel::NYTProf`](https://metacpan.org/module/Devel::NYTProf). Does connection, preparation, execution or the actual fetching take the most time?

Comment: i tried executing it in debug mode;where i noticed that execution takes more time than other processes..since preparation and connection are outside the loop,I have no problems with those things.

Comment: `s/benchmarked/profiled/`. There is a difference between “I noticed it took longer” and “oh, preparing is about 20ms each, so this can't be the issue. But this line here hogs 2mins, so let's investigate”. Please install NYTProf, run your script with `perl -d:NYTProf script.pl; nytprofhtml`, and look at the produced webpage in your browser. It marks expensive modules, lines, and subroutines with a red color.

Comment: Ok let me make a try on it.Thanks for your response.

Comment: You may want to select just the field(s) you are using instead of `select *`.

Comment: @amon Your comment about nytprof should be an answer.

Comment: What does DBI::Profile (which ships with DBI) tell you?

Comment: @amon:  NYTProf is an excellent suggestion, and I recommend it to everyone.  

One thing to note, though, is that NYTProf only shows you the time spent in Perl, and explicitly leaves out time spent in I/O and database access.  (That is, unless recent NYTProf versions have changed that.)  To profile the database itself, you'll want to use `DBI::Profile` or similar.

Comment: I had a program that called a web service, and NYTProf charged the time waiting for the service to respond to the SSL libraries.

Comment: You could set DBI_TRACE=1 and watch it run. Additionally, a few well placed breakpoints and/or print statements, and judicious use of the debugger can take you nice places.

Comment: Have tried indexing the relevant fields?